# Url variables and redirect

Tags: php, url, variables, redirect

When I have url with one variable like: `www.mysite.com/animals.php?pet=dogs` I do checks:

```
if (!isset($_GET['pet']) || empty($_GET['pet']) || ($pet_true === false)){
header('Location: error.php');
exit();
} echo 'list of dogs';
```

and I get redirect when pet isn't set or empty or false, so it works.

But I'd like to add second variable: `www.mysite.com/animals.php?pet=dogs&breed=collie` and do checks:

- if breed is not set or empty or false: redirect to error page.
- if url is: `?pet=dogs&madeup` : redirect to error page.

I thought I can do checks like:

```
if (!isset($_GET['breed']) || empty($_GET['breed']) || ($breed_true === false)){
header('Location: error.php');
exit();
} else {
       echo 'Collie info';
       }
```

but when url is correct `www.mysite.com/animals.php?pet=dogs` I get redirect anyway because breed is not set.

The only solution I can think of is to echo nothing:

```
if (!isset($_GET['breed']) || empty($_GET['breed']) || ($breed_true === false)){
    echo '';
} else {
       echo 'Collie info';
       }
```

But now after `?pet=dogs&` user can type whatever he wants and I don't know if it's safe, I think redirect to error page would be better, but is it possible to do??

Comment: what is `$pet_true` and `$breed_true` ?

Comment: What is the actual problem?

Comment: so if the `breed` is not set what do you want to happen?

Comment: `empty()` is essentially the concise equivalent to `!isset($var) || $var == false`, so no need to use `isset()`, if you are using `empty()`. Less code is better!